# Cannot see special character

Tags: characters

```
  \documentclass[11pt,table,a5paper]{article}
  \usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, outer=2.1cm, inner=1cm,twoside, headsep=26pt]{geometry}
  \usepackage{collcell}
  \begin{document}
      20 µg/mL
  \end{document}
```

In the above example mu is not visible. How can i fix this error?

Comment: `\usepackage{siunitx}` and then `\SI{20}{\micro\gram\per\milli\liter}`

Comment: `\usepackage{fontspec}` and compile with `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use Greek characters in text mode more often, you could consider loading the package `textgreek`. This is shown in my first version.

The second version is much more elegant and uses the package `siunitx`. I think, you should get used to this package, as it does a lot of nice work for you.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol-or-fraction]{siunitx} % for super easy handling of such cases.


  \begin{document}
With textgreek, it looks like 20 \textmu{}g/mL. 

You could also use the package siunitx and write \SI{20}{\micro\gram\per\milli\litre}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

siunitx gives a nicer fitting µ, a nicer (narrow) spacing, corrects your big L to a small l and gives you the possibility to change to a µg ml^-1 version or other things later on.

Answer (score 4):

If an input encoding (package `inputenc`) is not specified, then TeX maps the characters to the output font encoding directly, which is OT1 by default.
OT1 is restricted to 7-bit. The question does not say, in which encoding the TeX input file is written, but `µ` is mapped to 8-bit character(s) in most encodings (e.g., UTF-8, Latin 1, CP 1252). Then TeX will lost that character, because the font encoding OT1 does not provide a slot for it.

TeX can report the lost characters:

```
\tracinglostchars=2
```

Result for 8-bit encoding:

```
Missing character: There is no µ in font cmr10!
```

Result for UTF-8 (multi-byte):

```
Missing character: There is no � in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no � in font cmr10!
```

**Solution:**

- Package `inputenc` makes the 8-bit characters active to support them independently from the font encoding. `µ` is usually mapped to `\textmu`.
- Package `textcomp` uses the upright `µ` from font encoding `TS1`. Default
  font family is the EC fonts, an extension to the CM fonts for font encodings
  T1 and TS1.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
  20 µg/mL
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Further hints:**

- Recommended package for units: `siunitx`. Using logical markup makes it easier
  to change the appearances of the units (with numbers) via the many configuration options of `siunitx`.
- Package `fontspec` with Unicode fonts that include `µ` is recommended for users of LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

What if you use `$\mu$`, as long as you need a single character?

I would further advice to you to define a new command to denote micrograms per milliliter (??), such as

```
\newcommand{\unit}{\ensuremath{\mu}g/mL}
```

(if you denote liters with capital `L`).